# How to automatically reverse the IEEE journal name in JabRef?

Tags: bibtex, jabref

The journal name in the bib file downloaded from IEEE website is like 'Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, IEEE Transactions on'. Is there a way to automatically reverse the IEEE journal name in JabRef as 'IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence'?

One reason to do this is that sometimes it is requried to be written as 'IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence'. 
The other reason is that I want to produce a nice bibtexkey. For example 'IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence' is short for TPAMI, not ITOPAAMI or PAAMIITO.

Many thanks for helping.

Comment: Try with `Options` > `Manage journal abbreviations` and `Tools` > `Un/Abbreviate journal names` options.

Comment: @Fran Thank you. The bibtexkey problem could be solved by manually add both conditions and map them to the same abbreviation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments